# How to detect key down event for arrow key on textarea?

Tags: javascript, events, safari

Create the following html-page:

```
<textarea id="code" rows="10"></textarea>
<script>
  document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    alert(event.keyCode);
  }
</script>
```

Open it on **Mobile Safari** (on a simulator or on a device with keyboard), tap on textarea to start editing. And now press any arrow key - event won't fire.

How to detect key down for arrow keys?

P.S. Related issue on Apple Bug Report system: 13243285

Comment: I can't reproduce this on JsFiddle. [JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rNhkM/)

Comment: You may reproduce it only on Mobile Safari.

Comment: Hei @Altaveron, any news about this? It looks like after 2 years nothing changed? I still can reproduce this on Mobile Safari on iOS 9.0.1 ... did you find any solution so far?

Comment: Yes, something was changed. Now there are much more issues in iOS...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Official answer from Apple:

> Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS). Our
>   engineers have reviewed your request and have concluded that there is
>   no supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the
>   currently shipping system configurations.

Comment: Is there still no way of capturing these events?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(selector).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       alert( "left pressed" );
       return false;
    }
});
```

Character codes:

37 - left

38 - up

39 - right

40 - down

Comment: Don't work on Mobile Safari. And it's the same as on the question.