# How to detect arrow keys using JavaScript on iPad with Bluetooth keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, keyboard-events

I cannot find a way to detect arrow keys in a text field in Safari and Chrome on an iPad when a bluetooth keyboard is used.
Using this test HTML and JavaScript, touch the input field to give it focus.
Using the arrow keys nothing happens, but type letters and numbers and the keydown events occur.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test page.</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input id="input" style="width: 600px;" type="textarea" />
  </form>
  <div id="keydisp" style="width 600px; height: 50px"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
      var keyCode = event.which;
      document.getElementById("keydisp").innerHTML = "key pressed: " + keyCode;
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to detect the arrows?

Comment: try checking `window.event`, not just the `event` that gets passed. ex: `var keyCode = event.which || window.event;`

Comment: @basher That will not help.  According to the jQuery **keydown** documentation `jQuery normalizes the .which property so you can reliably use it to retrieve the key code`.

Comment: Is the even even firing? Add this to the begining of your function and see if you get the pop up. `alert('keydown event');` I would do this myself but I left my iPad at work. Also; does the event fire for printable characters (A-Z, numbers, etc..)?

Comment: @AndrewBonsall I have tried doing keydown and other events. It does fire for other characters. Events for Arrow keys and tabs don't work.

Comment: I'm sorry I just found this, which based on what you have told me, nothing has changed [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959048/how-to-detect-key-down-event-for-arrow-key-on-textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959048/how-to-detect-key-down-event-for-arrow-key-on-textarea)

Comment: And the reason for the down-vote on a working example.??? I see someone woke up with a bad mood as it seems...

Comment: @PeterDarmis probably because your code is essentially the same as what I posted.  The issue is that the keydown event never gets fired when using a bluetooth keyboard on the ipad.  This is probably something that needs fixed in Safari.  It would be nice if someone could find a work-around.

Comment: @SeanN. you mean only Safari does not detect arrow keys with neither one of the answers using a wireless keyboard on ipad? Do the rest of the most popular browsers detect it, using examples from answers on your ipad?

Comment: @SeanN. Now if this is only a problem for you in safari then i would advise the following but please add some feedback to see if this is a good tactic and to add it in answer. use `keypress` for safari. Additionally you could try on `keypress` the following   `if (event.which == null)
     char= String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);    // old IE
  else if (event.which != 0 && event.charCode != 0)
     char= String.fromCharCode(event.which);   // All others
  else
     // special key` check chapter 5. in http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: @SeanN. this is a well chosen question my edited answer includes a small snippet which shows you some of the `KeyboardEvent` attributes that in this case are needed. Some are deprecated some are not, some will be according to MDN, you can try a cross-browser check. You will probably solve this with a combination of `event.key` and `event.code`

Answer (score 13):

I understand that this might seem like a grim answer and I apologise if it is.

I have struggled with this issue a few weeks ago and eventually gave up on it.
Countless hours of trying to get the arrow keys on the iPad to fire the `onkeydown` event did seem to work at all, it was like they weren't even being pressed.

A good alternative for a game (or something like that) is to use the `WSAD` keys, *this was what I did*.

The codes for the `WSAD` keys are:

```
w: 87,
s: 83,
a: 65,
d: 68
```

This is how you would normally detect when the `WSAD` keys have been pressed:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.which == 87) {
    // W key Has Been Pressed
  } else if (event.which == 83) {
    // S key Has Been Pressed
  } else if (event.which == 65) {
    // A key Has Been Pressed
  } else if (event.which == 68) {
    // D key Has Been Pressed
  }
  // prevent the default action
  // event.preventDefault(); // This is optional.
});
```

The codes for the arrow keys are:

```
up: 38,
down: 40,
left: 37,
right: 39
```

This is how you would normally detect when the arrows keys have been pressed:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.which == 37) {
    // Left Arrow Has Been Pressed
  } else if (event.which == 38) {
    // Up Arrow Has Been Pressed
  } else if (event.which == 39) {
    // Right Arrow Has Been Pressed
  } else if (event.which == 40) {
    // Down Arrow Has Been Pressed
  }
  // prevent the default action
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

NOTE: you can only use the `onkeydown` event to check if the the arrow keys have been pressed.

You can also use `var key = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;`
Quoting [Peter Darmis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2560539/peter-darmis):

> Versions of Opera before 10.50 messes up by returning non-zero `event.which` values for four special keys (Insert, Delete, Home and End), meaning using `event.keyCode` may be more "fail safe" across older browsers.
>   [Source](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html)

Quoting the jQuery api:

> The event.which property normalizes `event.keyCode` and `event.charCode`. It is recommended to watch `event.which` for keyboard key input. For more detail, read about `event.charCode` on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode).
>   [Source](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

Good luck, and all the best.

Comment: Can you please write in your answer regarding `charCode` which is normailzed by `.which()`... again *quote by Peter Darmis* if you want i don't mind... the [notes][https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode#Notes] of charCode in MDN and specially the part with `keydown` and `charCode`??? If i remember it writes `charCode is never set in the keydown and keyup events. In these cases, keyCode is set instead.`

Comment: As you understand @Mango i am not here to argue anyone, i just posted my answer. I am also learning from this website... and a lot :) now since which normalizes `keyCode` and `charCode` it means that most probably (i have not seen internal code of which() ever) it uses both in a proper way. So basically you could say that in my answer the `var key = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;` part is a redundancy. No it is proper coding. Since `keyCode` is set on `keydown` you could try first of all to see if you get value from that, if it fails then you can move to using `which()`

Comment: this is a part of latest jQuery... `// Includes some event props shared by KeyEvent and MouseEvent
 props: ( "altKey bubbles cancelable ctrlKey currentTarget detail eventPhase " +
  "metaKey relatedTarget shiftKey target timeStamp view which" ).split( " " ),

 fixHooks: {},

 keyHooks: {
  props: "char charCode key keyCode".split( " " ),
  filter: function( event, original ) {

   // Add which for key events
   if ( event.which == null ) {
    event.which = original.charCode != null ? original.charCode : original.keyCode;
   }

   return event;
  }
 },`

Comment: @PeterDarmis Thanks for the update, I'm looking into it. Also if you would like to give me more input you can use http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113088/discussion-between-mango-and-peter-darmis, I have `desktop notifications` enabled and I can respond to your messages faster.

Answer (score 4):

For most browsers you could use something like

```js
function returnKeyCode(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  switch (keyCode) {
    case 37:
      alert(e.code ? e.code : e.key);
      break;
    case 38:
      alert(e.code ? e.code : e.key);
      break;
    case 39:
      alert(e.code ? e.code : e.key);
      break;
    case 40:
      alert(e.code ? e.code : e.key);
      break;
    default:
      alert(e.code ? e.code : e.key);
  }
}
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  returnKeyCode(e);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But if you would like to be more thorough take a look at the following snippet. Before that take a look on [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) attributes that are used and will be deprecated, or are deprecated.

PS: check the difference in event.code when using jQuery(red) and when javascript(blue).

```js
$(document).on("keydown", function(event) {
  $("#keydown").append("<br><span>keyCode</span>= " + event.keyCode);
  $("#keydown").append("<br><span>key</span>= " + event.key);
  $("#keydown").append("<br><span>code</span>= " + event.code);
  $("#keydown").append("<br><span>which</span>= " + event.which);
  $("#keydown").append("<br><span>charCode</span>= " + event.charCode);
  $("#keydown").append("<br><span>char</span>= " + event.char);
  $("#keydown").append("<br><span>keyIdentifier</span>= " + event.keyIdentifier);
}).on("keypress", function(event) {
  $("#keypress").append("<br><span>keyCode</span> = " + event.keyCode);
  $("#keypress").append("<br><span>key</span> = " + event.key);
  $("#keypress").append("<br><span>code</span> = " + event.code);
  $("#keypress").append("<br><span>which</span> = " + event.which);
  $("#keypress").append("<br><span>charCode</span> = " + event.charCode);
  $("#keypress").append("<br><span>char</span>= " + event.char);
  $("#keypress").append("<br><span>keyIdentifier</span>= " + event.keyIdentifier);
}).on("keyup", function(event) {
  $("#keyup").append("<br><span>keyCode</span> = " + event.keyCode);
  $("#keyup").append("<br><span>key</span> = " + event.key);
  $("#keyup").append("<br><span>code</span> = " + event.code);
  $("#keyup").append("<br><span>which</span> = " + event.which);
  $("#keyup").append("<br><span>charCode</span> = " + event.charCode);
  $("#keyup").append("<br><span>char</span>= " + event.char);
  $("#keyup").append("<br><span>keyIdentifier</span>= " + event.keyIdentifier);
});
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  $("#keydown").append("<br><i>keyCode</i>= " + event.keyCode);
  $("#keydown").append("<br><i>key</i>= " + event.key);
  $("#keydown").append("<br><i>code</i>= " + event.code);
  $("#keydown").append("<br><i>which</i>= " + event.which);
  $("#keydown").append("<br><i>charCode</i>= " + event.charCode);
  $("#keydown").append("<br><i>char</i>= " + event.char);
  $("#keydown").append("<br><i>keyIdentifier</i>= " + event.keyIdentifier);
});
window.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
  $("#keypress").append("<br><i>keyCode</i>= " + event.keyCode);
  $("#keypress").append("<br><i>key</i>= " + event.key);
  $("#keypress").append("<br><i>code</i>= " + event.code);
  $("#keypress").append("<br><i>which</i>= " + event.which);
  $("#keypress").append("<br><i>charCode</i>= " + event.charCode);
  $("#keypress").append("<br><i>char</i>= " + event.char);
  $("#keypress").append("<br><i>keyIdentifier</i>= " + event.keyIdentifier);
});
window.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
  $("#keyup").append("<br><i>keyCode</i>= " + event.keyCode);
  $("#keyup").append("<br><i>key</i>= " + event.key);
  $("#keyup").append("<br><i>code</i>= " + event.code);
  $("#keyup").append("<br><i>which</i>= " + event.which);
  $("#keyup").append("<br><i>charCode</i>= " + event.charCode);
  $("#keyup").append("<br><i>char</i>= " + event.char);
  $("#keyup").append("<br><i>keyIdentifier</i>= " + event.keyIdentifier);
});
$(document).on("click", function() {
$("span, i").remove();
});
```

```css
span {
  color:#f00;
}
i {
  color:#00f;  
}
.container {
display:inline-flex;
width:100%;
height:auto;
align-items: stretch;
align-content: center;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: row;
}
.container div{
align-self: stretch;
width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div id="keydown">Keydown Event</div>
<div id="keypress">Keypress Event</div>
<div id="keyup">Keyup Event</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please remember that `event.keyCode` is **NOT** supported in *all* browsers, `event.which` is normalized by jQuery, meaning it works across *all* browsers.

Comment: doesn't this little piece of code `var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;`, satisfy the fact that `event.keyCode` is NOT supported in all browsers??? @Mango Can you please tell me from that line what will be the value of `var keyCode` if `e.keyCode` is undefined?

Comment: Granted the `keyCode` variable will not be undefined but that is not my point, what I'm saying is, what is the point of checking if `event.keyCode` is supported when you know for a fact that `event.which` is always going to be supported?

Comment: Yes you are right at that `event.which` is well supported by almost all `latest` browsers. So why should we check for `event.keyCode`? But those two are not exactly the same in the first way... And check this too - http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html - regarding `event.which`: "Versions of Opera before 10.50 messes up by returning non-zero event.which values for four special keys (Insert, Delete, Home and End). " It is more fail safe across older browsers. That is why i use `event.keyCode` as well. But yet thanks for your down-vote it was well explained. @Mango

Comment: The event.which property normalizes `event.keyCode` and `event.charCode`. It is recommended to watch `event.which` for keyboard key input. `event.which` also normalizes button presses (`mousedown` and `mouseupevents`), reporting 1 for left button, 2 for middle, and 3 for right. Source: https://api.jquery.com/event.which/. Why use something that *might* follow standards over something that **DOES** follow standards?

Comment: I have down voted your answer because of this reason, although I now feel like our discussion has come to a dead end simply because neither of us are wrong. My vote can only be changed by only if you edit your post. Thank you for this learning experience I hope, we can do it again sometime. Good night.

Comment: `event.keyCode` and `event.which` are not identical, if they where one of them would have been deprecated or would stop being used eventually. Since each one has different action on some browsers and/or browser versions, it should be clever enough to understand that `e.which` is an excellent choice for an answer and well spoken. But using both in combination is simply better. Anyway, thanks for the down-vote. In here you can get down-voted for being right. Nice!!! @Mango

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113088/discussion-between-mango-and-peter-darmis).

Comment: I tried your last code snippet in both Chrome and Safari on the iPad with the Bluetooth keyboard.  Here is the output of the "up" arrow key: http://imgur.com/yg5UsFE

Comment: @SeanN. not very good image :( last thing i would like to throw on the table is something like this http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112499/configuring-custom-keys-on-bluetooth-keyboard. If there is a way to reconfigure the keys then do it. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

This might be an additional or something to what the others have given. In this example, key `W` is being checked if pressed.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
     var event = e.which || e.keyCode;
     if (event == 87){ alert("C was Pressed."); }
});
```

You can check if `keyCode` or `which` is usable, depending on your browser type and version.

> For more [Keyboard Events Info](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html).
>
> For [Event Keycodes](http://keycode.info/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably caused by default behaviour of pressing arrow keys in a iPad. Normally arrow keys scroll the document. But when the text field is focused, the default is prevented. It may be in the implementation of the browser which also stops the bubbling.

Instead of listening to document events, you can also listen to input field's events. See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gnqw4nqe/). I don't have a bluetooth keyboard so I can't test it. Sorry if it doesn't work.

```js
$(document).keydown(
function (event) {
        var keyCode = event.which;
        document.getElementById("keydisp").innerHTML = "key pressed: " + keyCode;
});

$("input").keydown(
function (event) {
        var keyCode = event.which;
        document.getElementById("keydisp").innerHTML = "key pressed: " + keyCode;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="textarea" id="input" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" style="width: 600px;">
<div id="keydisp" style="width 600px; height: 50px"></div>
```

Comment: Tested this.  I get key down messages for alpha numeric keys and so on, but not the arrow keys.  When the text input field has focus, the up arrow positions the text caret to the start of the text and down arrow positions the caret to the end of the text.

Comment: Ok, whoever downvoted this, can you explain yourself. Other answers don't even address the problem and say something completely irrelevant with the question. What might be my flaw that is bigger than theirs?

Comment: The input event doesn't trigger with the arrow keys on the ipad.